# Gpg4Win's Kleopatra not uploading to servers due to a "no name" error

Tags: openpgp, gpg4win, kleopatra

The server is visible and functional on my side, I just can't upload anything to any servers due to the same "No Name" error, I've tried different certificates (*.asc files) and nothing works.

Error:

[image: Error Image here]

Answer (score 0):

Very important apparently: the correct server must be used. Visiting the website proves that the web ui works, however the API that software uses doesn't work with the specified keyserver. I swapped to keyserver.ubuntu.com and it fixed itself

Answer (score 0):

**`sks-keyservers` is no more**, ceased to be, expired, late, and pushing up the daisies. (It *probably* wouldn't voom if you put 4 million volts through it, but I don't advise doing the experiment.) If you go to `https://sks-keyservers.net/` (no `pool`) and override the warning for expired certificate, you get a page with a red-bordered box containing:

```
This service is deprecated. This means it is no longer maintained, and new HKPS certificates will not be issued. Service reliability should not be expected.

Update 2021-06-21: Due to even more GDPR takedown requests, the DNS records for the pool will no longer be provided at all.
```

You can also get this page without the cert error from Wayback e.g. https://web.archive.org/web/20210628154653/https://sks-keyservers.net/ .